# How to convert current screen to Bitmap?

Tags: android

I'm using **OVERLAY** view  to view surfaceview on all the other views. So I **DON'T** want to take a screenshot of my **ROOT** view. Are there ways to take screenshot of my screen?

Comment: Did u try taking screen shot of decorview, that is getWindow().getDecorView() ?

Comment: @RameesThattarath I haven't done that, but is it obvious that it works with outside of application?

Comment: @ProJser : Hope this will help you : https://medium.com/@ssaurel/taking-a-screenshot-programmatically-in-android-apps-67619cb80bf8